# Can Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0 use OCSP for revocation?

Tags: ssl

We have a very old app running on windows server 2012 that uses the *Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0* http client to connect to an API. The problem is that we occasionally get this certificate revocation error:

> Revocation information for the security certificate for this site is not available. Do you want to proceed?

The certificate in question is issued by Let's Encrypt. Let's Encrypt does not support CRL, so I am wondering if the reason for the message is *Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0*'s use of CRL to check for certificate revocation.

So my question is, is *Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0* only capable of CRL, or is it also capable of OCSP? If it is only capable of CRL, then that would explain the error message we are getting. We also only get the error message occasionally, which suggests to me that the CRL is only checked occasionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server hosting the revocation list was blocked by the firewall. After unblocking it, everything worked.